# How to force 'gulp-sftp' plugin to keep the connection, avoid connecting and disconnecting each time?

Tags: node.js, ssh, gulp, sublimetext, sftp

While Gulp-SFTP connecting/disconnecting, it can take much time. Plugin doesn't have options to keep connection. It uses ssh2 (https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2) to handle connections.

Is there any way to avoid disconnections and save time? Maybe there are some other plugins with the similar functionality?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just found another solution.

I can use OSXFUSE with SSHFS to mount remote linux directory to my Mac, and use Gulp to work with it as with the native local directory. No more delays when saving files, less plugins and more time savings.

You can get OSXFUSE and SSHFS [here](http://osxfuse.github.io).

Macfusion - handy GUI to add remote drives, can be found [here](http://macfusionapp.org)